# ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'feedinputp_.client' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working on a Hibernate project and I have this code in my DAO:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ClientKey",referencedColumnName="ClientKey")
public Client getClient() {
    return client;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}
```

My table desc:

```
'FeedKey', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'ClientKey', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'CreatedBy', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'CreatedTs', 'datetime', 'YES', '', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ''
'JobInstanceKey', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'LogicalDeleteTms', 'datetime', 'YES', '', '2037-12-31 00:00:00', ''
'ParamName', 'varchar(128)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'ParamOper', 'varchar(64)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'ParamValue', 'varchar(1024)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'ParamValueType', 'varchar(64)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'SourceInstanceKey', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'UpdatedTs', 'datetime', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Updatedby', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'ParamKey', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
```

But the query that Hibernate generates is as follows:

```
select
    feedinputp_.paramKey,
    feedinputp_.client as client10_,
    feedinputp_.createdBy as createdBy10_,
    feedinputp_.createdTs as createdTs10_,
from
    M_FeedInputParams feedinputp_ 
where
    feedinputp_.paramKey=?;
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You will need to show your table definition

Comment: It is not really hard to debug. The column client does not exist on M_FeedInputParams table. =)

Comment: but i am trying use it as a foreign key so am seting that as client type

Comment: Can you show your hibernate query and mapping of M_FeedInputParams and Client?